# Working with jQuery wrap function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap an input element with a div, and then append another element to the wrapping div.

Markup:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="foo" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>'),
somethingElse = $('<div class="something-else"></div>');

$('#foo').wrap(wrapper);
wrapper.append(somethingElse);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckpeZ/

The problem is the "somethingElse" div is not getting appended to wrapper. It is like the line `wrapper.append(somethingElse)` is completely ignored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The wrapper is being cloned, you need to append to the new element that was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper is being cloned, you need to append to the new element that was created.

```
var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>'),
somethingElse = $('<div class="something-else"></div>');

$('#foo').wrap(wrapper).parent().append(somethingElse);
// or
$('#foo').wrap(wrapper).after(somethingElse);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ckpeZ/4/

Answer (score 2):

you're appending '`somethingElse`' to the wrapper, a reference that is no longer relevant after you 'wrap' foo.

this is ugly, but gets the idea across -- you should be able to simply:

```
$('#foo').wrap(wrapper);
$('#foo').parents('.wrapper').append(somethingElse);
```